# Как правильно сохранить данные в бд

Tags: python, ооп, django

Привет всем, я не понимаю как правильно сделать запись в бд, неправильно не хочу писать и хочется разобраться. 
Есть пасрер который возвращает список с данными определенного типа, вот эти данные нужно сохранить, но кто должен сохранять эти данные? Модель? Парсер? или другой объект специально предназначенный для этого? Прощу написать небольшой пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос концептуальный, то есть понятно как написать код, но непонятно куда его положить, то я бы посоветовал не прикручивать к парсеру функционал сохранения данных. 
Можно это сохранение сделать во вьюхе, а совсем хорошо написать отдельный модуль с классом-контроллером, который бы получал данные для сохранения, дальше итерировался по ним и создавал/сохранял модели, сформированные из этих данных (ну там MyModel.objects.create(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2) и т.д.) В этом случае во вьюхе можно получить данные из парсера и передать их экземпляру контроллера, который их и сохранит. Вся логика по обработке данных будет располагаться в объекте контроллера, что удобно и красиво будет.

**upd**
Заведите модуль в директории с приложением, назовем его `controllers.py`

```
# controllers.py
class LessonController(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(LessonController, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def save_parsed_data(self):
        for item in self.data:
            Lesson.objects.create(
                subject=item.subject,
                teacher=item.teacher,
                ...
            )

# views.py
from controllers import LessonController

def my_view(request):
    x = Parser("D:/rsp.xls")
    schedule = x.parse()

    lesson_ctl = LessonController(schedule)
    lesson_ctl.save_parsed_data
```

Ну вот что-то в этом духе может вам подойдет.

Comment: Я так и хотел сделать, можете пример небольшой написать, я написал подобное, но мне за него стыдно.

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

Смутно понятно как-то, но если это то, что я понял, сделайте во вьюшке так, например:

```
from .models import Имятвоеймодели

def some_function(request):
че-нибудь = Имятвоеймодели()
че-нибудь.полемодели = какие-тоданныеотпарсера
че-нибудь.save()
```

А вообще подробнее опишите свой парсер, дайте пример кода.

Comment: Модель имеет такую же структуру как и Lesson
    
    class Lesson:
        def __init__(self):
            self.subject = str()
            self.teacher = str()
            self.group   = str()
            self.n_group = str()
            self.classroom = str()
            self.number = int()


    x = Parser("D:/rsp.xls")
    x.parsing()
    x.schedule # Это список имеющий тип Lesson, вот его и нужно в бд сохранить.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не импортировать sql драйвер и уже от этого плясать, данные записать в переменные и их передать в базу?
import sqlite3 например.

Comment: Я так и делаю, но не пойму где это сохранение сделать.